# Los datos de Retrofit.body() cargan a NULL

Tags: java, json, rest, retrofit, swagger

Desde una aplicacion swagger llamo a un servicio rest y recupera el siguiente JSON (solo os pongo la parte body que es la que interesa):

```
"body": {
        "PAPIACCVENSALFOR": {
            "PAPIACCVENSALFOR": [
                {
                    "IDCLIECESS": "11516095",
                    "TASK_NUMBER": "3121",
                    "NEXT_DATE": "",
                    "TASK_SUBJECT": "",
                    "COLLABORATOR_NUMBER": "00511818730",
                    "COLLABORATOR_NAME": "PERICO EL DE LOS PALOTES",
                    "ASSIGNED_OFFICE": "020",
                    "BRANCH_DESCRIPTION": "ALICANTE",
                    "OPEN_DATE": "20210315",
                    "COMMENTS": "estoy en pruebas"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

He creado las siguientes clases (la siguiente clase es contenida por la anterior, y todas tienes sus metodos GET y SET pero no los pongo aquí para ahorrarmelo) para recuperar los datos del json:

```
public class TeneoOnlineResponse {
    
    @SerializedName("PAPIACCVENSALFOR")
    @Expose
    private Papiaccvensalfor papiaccvensalfor;

public class Papiaccvensalfor {
    
    @SerializedName("PAPIACCVENSALFOR")
    @Expose
    private List<PapiaccvensalforSon> papiaccvensalforSon;

public class PapiaccvensalforSon {
    
    @SerializedName("IDCLIECESS")
    @Expose
    private String idcliecess;
    
    @SerializedName("TASK_NUMBER")
    @Expose
    private String taskNumber;
    
    @SerializedName("NEXT_DATE")
    @Expose
    private String nextDate;
```

Aclaro que la clase PapiaccvensalforSon  tiene de variables todos los datos del array del Json.

Para llamar a dicho webservice rest utilizo el refrofit de la siguiente manera:

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(Level.BODY));

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ConfiguracionInfo.getStrUrlTeneoOnLine())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

Y ésta es la interfaz:

```
@POST("salesforce/2/getaccionventa")
Call<TeneoOnlineResponse> getUrlTeneoOnline(@Body TeneoOnlineBody teneoOnlineBody);
```

Hago la llamada del interfaz de la siguiente manera:

```
Call<TeneoOnlineResponse> call = TeneoOnlineServiceGenerator.createService(TeneoOnlineService.class).getUrlTeneoOnline(body);
            Response<TeneoOnlineResponse> retrofitResponse = call.execute();
            
            if(retrofitResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                log.info("[TeneoOnlineClient]  devolvio 200");
                teneoOnlineResponse = retrofitResponse.body();
                papiaccvensalfor = teneoOnlineResponse.getPapiaccvensalfor();
                log.info("[TeneoOnlineClient]  OK");
            }
```

He visto que la llamada me devuelve un 200 (ok) pero cuando los datos de *teneoOnlineResponse.getPapiaccvensalfor();* es **null** . He realizado esta prueba con la herramienta Postman y sí me devuelve datos.

¿Podríais echarme una mano?

Cualquier duda o aclaración, decídmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si en el `body` hay un JSON que tiene el atributo "body", deberás mapearlo también.

Comment: Si te refieres al parametro de entrada de la interfaz, está mapeado correctamente. Perdón no lo añadí